# Django tutorial part5 error

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django programming

I am playing with part5

I'll leave the address below

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial05/

I added the contents of the test file

but I did the test, but there was a problem with the test file

I tried to find a typo but I can not find it

What is the problem?

this is Traceback

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/choco/python3/django/mysite/polls/tests.py", line 96, in test_two_past_questions
    create_question(question_text="Past question 1.", days=-30)
NameError: name 'create_question' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 8 tests in 0.103s

FAILED (errors=5)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

This is tests.py

```html
import datetime

from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Question

class QuestionModelTests(TestCase):

    def test_was_published_recently_with_old_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() returns False for questions whose pub_date
        is older than 1 day.
        """
        time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=1)
        old_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertIs(old_question.was_published_recently(), False)

    def test_was_published_recently_with_recent_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() returns True for questions whose pub_date
        is within the last day.
        """
        time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=23, minutes=59, seconds=59)
        recent_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertIs(recent_question.was_published_recently(), True)

    def test_was_published_recently_wiht_future_question(self):
        """
        test_was_published_recently() returns False for questions whose pub_date
        is in the test_was_published_recently_wiht_future_question
        """
        time = timezone.now() +datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertIs(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)

    def create_question(question_text, days):
        """
        Create a question with the given `question_text` and published the
        given number of `days` offset to now (negative for questions published
        in the past, positive for questions that have yet to be published).
        """
        time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
        return Question.objects.create(question_text=question_text, pub_date=time)

class QuestionIndexViewTests(TestCase):
    def test_no_questions(self):
        """
        If no questions exist, an appropriate message is displayed.
        """
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.")
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

    def test_past_question(self):
        """
        Questions with a pub_date in the past are displayed on the
        index page.
        """
        create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context['latest_question_list'],
            ['<Question: Past question.>']
        )

    def test_future_question(self):
        """
        Questions with a pub_date in the future aren't displayed on
        the index page.
        """
        create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.")
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

    def test_future_question_and_past_question(self):
        """
        Even if both past and future questions exist, only past questions
        are displayed.
        """
        create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
        create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context['latest_question_list'],
            ['<Question: Past question.>']
        )

    def test_two_past_questions(self):
        """
        The questions index page may display multiple questions.
        """
        create_question(question_text="Past question 1.", days=-30)
        create_question(question_text="Past question 2.", days=-5)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context['latest_question_list'],
            ['<Question: Past question 2.>', '<Question: Past question 1.>']
        )
```

this is views.py

```html
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Choice, Question

# ...
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
        published in the future).
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())

class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn more about OOP. Check this code with corrections:

```
import datetime

from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Question

class QuestionModelTests(TestCase):

    def test_was_published_recently_with_old_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() returns False for questions whose pub_date
        is older than 1 day.
        """
        time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=1)
        old_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertIs(old_question.was_published_recently(), False)

    def test_was_published_recently_with_recent_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() returns True for questions whose pub_date
        is within the last day.
        """
        time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=23, minutes=59, seconds=59)
        recent_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertIs(recent_question.was_published_recently(), True)

    def test_was_published_recently_wiht_future_question(self):
        """
        test_was_published_recently() returns False for questions whose pub_date
        is in the test_was_published_recently_wiht_future_question
        """
        time = timezone.now() +datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertIs(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)

    def create_question(self, question_text, days):
        """
        Create a question with the given `question_text` and published the
        given number of `days` offset to now (negative for questions published
        in the past, positive for questions that have yet to be published).
        """
        time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
        return Question.objects.create(question_text=question_text, pub_date=time)

class QuestionIndexViewTests(TestCase):
    def create_question(self, question_text, days):
        """
        Create a question with the given `question_text` and published the
        given number of `days` offset to now (negative for questions published
        in the past, positive for questions that have yet to be published).
        """
        time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
        return Question.objects.create(question_text=question_text, pub_date=time)

    def test_no_questions(self):
        """
        If no questions exist, an appropriate message is displayed.
        """
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.")
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

    def test_past_question(self):
        """
        Questions with a pub_date in the past are displayed on the
        index page.
        """
        self.create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context['latest_question_list'],
            ['<Question: Past question.>']
        )

    def test_future_question(self):
        """
        Questions with a pub_date in the future aren't displayed on
        the index page.
        """
        self.create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.")
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

    def test_future_question_and_past_question(self):
        """
        Even if both past and future questions exist, only past questions
        are displayed.
        """
        self.create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
        self.create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context['latest_question_list'],
            ['<Question: Past question.>']
        )

    def test_two_past_questions(self):
        """
        The questions index page may display multiple questions.
        """
        self.create_question(question_text="Past question 1.", days=-30)
        self.create_question(question_text="Past question 2.", days=-5)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context['latest_question_list'],
            ['<Question: Past question 2.>', '<Question: Past question 1.>']
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You've indented `create_question` so that it's within the QuestionModelTests class. I don't think you meant to do that - it's not used in that class and does not reference any class attributes. You should unindent it so that it is outside all classes.